# itext7 error in .net core web application: AdobeGlyphList

Tags: .net-core, itext7

I'm using iText 7.1.10 and .net core 3.0.

If I generate a pdf with a console application, there is no problem, but if I generate the same pdf in a web application, I have the error :

AdobeGlyphList.txt loading error: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception.

Have you encountered this problem and do you have solutions?

Thank You

Comment: Please attach the necessary information to reproduce the problem: example project file and code and steps to run the app

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thank you, i found the solution : Add package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions

Answer (score 10):

Solution : Add package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will be fixed in iText 7.2.0. https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/commit/6206203e2643ea1563917ddfeca8feb2b1cf1dcc

For now, explicitly adding the package Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions should fix the issue, as Bob mentioned.

I faced this issue after migration to .NET 5. But in .NET 5 [this package was removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/platformabstractions-package-removed).